# Waterfall chart sort by division

Tags: powerbi

Is it posssible to sort the chart below by quarter?

[image]

The year is correctly sorted, but the quarter seems impossible to sort! I tried "Sort by column" and all possible format configurations but how to sort this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Quarter column and remove "Q" using Split Column option,change column Data type in to Whole number then sort it